# Add Custom Widget to listWidget on pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I used Qt Designer to make two .ui files, one is the Main Window of my application, and the second is a custom widget I made. My idea was to fill a listWidget on my Main application with this custom Widget to display data.

I made this code, which compiles without problem but it does not show the customWidget on the List when it runs

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout,QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindowReclamo import Ui_MainWindow
from widgetReclamos import Ui_Form

#Custom Widget*
class WidgetReclamo(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        print("I am Alive")

        
#My Main Program*
class ProgramaReclamos(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #I create an Item*
        Item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        #I create a custom widget*
        Item_Widget = WidgetReclamo()
        #I set the Size from the Item to the same of the widget*
        Item.setSizeHint(Item_Widget.sizeHint())
        #I add it to the list*
        self.listWidget.addItem(Item)

        self.listWidget.setItemWidget(Item, Item_Widget)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = ProgramaReclamos()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I saw some questions online which their answer were for PyQt4 and they said something about using a Layout for the Widget, but I don´t understand if I have to make one because the widget was made in the .ui file

Comment: Execute this: `print(Item_Widget.sizeHint())`

Comment: Change `Item.setSizeHint(Item_Widget.sizeHint())` to `Item.setSizeHint(Item_Widget.size())`

Comment: My god, it worked. Man, thank you so much! you have helped me two times in a row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EYLLANESC said on the comment:

> Change Item.setSizeHint(Item_Widget.sizeHint()) to Item.setSizeHint(Item_Widget.size()) – eyllanesc

Thank you !